# How to assign numpy arrays to a string variable using exec?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, exec, eval

I want to assign numpy arrays to a string variable using `exec` method.

```
x = np.random.rand(3,2)
y = np.random.rand(4)
z = np.random.rand(2,2)

r = ['x','y','z']

for i in r:
    exec("%s = %g"%(i,eval(i)+2))
```

But when I execute the code it gives the error

> TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray

If I convert the arrays to scalar then it works,

```
for i in r:
    exec("%s = %f"%(i,eval(i).sum()))
```

How do we assign numpy arrays to a string variable?

Comment: Even when it works, it is bad python style.

Comment: The string display of a numpy array does not `exec` back to an array.

Comment: I know its a bad python style but its a personal project and I am experimenting with some things in python.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to do. You already have arrays called `x, y, z` in your namespace, so why are you trying to create new variables `x, y, z` pointing to the same arrays?

If you have a numpy array called `a` and you wanted to create a new variable `x` pointing to it, you could do

```
exec('%s = %s' % ('x', 'a'))
```

which is of course the same as `x = a`.

It's quite unlikely that you actually need to use `exec` for this problem. If you want to give names (contained in a list) for a bunch of arrays, you should look into the Python `dict` container, rather than creating namespace variables. For example:

```
array_di = dict()
keys = ['x', 'y', 'z']
arrays = [np.random.randn(3), np.random.randn(4), np.random.randn(5)]
for k, a in zip(keys, arrays):
    array_di[k] = a
```

or as an one-liner:

```
array_di = {k: a for k, a in zip(keys, arrays)}
```

Then you can access the arrays as `array_di['x']` for example.